# How Do I create multiple Top Level Admin Menu Pages To submit data to the options table?

Tags: admin-menu, settings-api, options

I am trying to create more than one top level options page in my wordpress theme. But right now I can only save the data for one. How can I save the data for two without having to create tabbed panels?

```
// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'baw_create_menu');

function baw_create_menu() {

//create new top-level menu
 add_menu_page('BAW Plugin Settings', 'BAW Settings', 'administrator', 'baw-settings', 'baw_settings_page');

//call register settings function
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}


function register_mysettings() {
//register our settings
register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
}

function baw_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Your Plugin Name</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php settings_fields( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo get_option('new_option_name'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo get_option('some_other_option'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo get_option('option_etc'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php submit_button(); ?>

   </form>
   </div>
   <?php 
}


// create second custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'bax_create_menu');

function bax_create_menu() {

//create new top-level menu
add_menu_page('BAX Plugin Settings', 'BAX Settings', 'administrator', 'bax-settings', 'bax_settings_page');

//call register settings function
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_settings' );
}


function register_settings() {
//register our settings
register_setting( 'bax-settings-group', 'option_name' );
register_setting( 'bax-settings-group', 'other_option' );
register_setting( 'bax-settings-group', 'etc' );
}

function bax_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Your Plugin Name</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php settings_fields( 'bax-settings-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'bax-settings-group' ); ?>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo get_option('option_name'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo get_option('other_option'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo get_option('etc'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer!! The problem I was having was having multiple forms being submitted to the options database. I found a tutorial that solved this problem:

WordPress Settings API: Multiple Forms On Same Page

http://www.mendoweb.be/blog/wordpress-settings-api-multiple-forms-on-same-page/